# Select voltando valores nulos no banco de dados

Tags: banco-de-dados, delphi, firebird, firebird-2.5

```
SELECT S.ID_SALES,
       S.ID_CLIENT,
       C.FULL_NAME,
       S.SDATE,
       coalesce(S.billed, 'N') BILLED,
       P.product_description product,
       I.amount,
       I.unit_cost, 
       I.unit_cost * I.amount SUBTOTAL,
       coalesce(I.discount, 0) DISCOUNT,
       (I.amount * I.unit_cost) - coalesce(I.discount, 0) TOTAL

FROM SELES S INNER JOIN CLIENTS C ON C.id_client = S.id_client
             inner join ITEM_SELES I ON I.id_sales = S.id_sales
             INNER JOIN PRODUCTS P on P.id_product = I.id_product
WHERE 1=1
ORDER BY C.FULL_NAME,
         P.product_description
```

Quando dou um select no meu Banco de Dados todos os campo voltam como null mesmo tendo dados registrados, porem quando uso apenas o primeiro INNER JOIN com seus campos funciona normalmente.

Na forma abaixo funciona normalmente:

```
SELECT V.ID_SALES,
       V.ID_CLIENT,
       V.SDATE,
       coalesce(V.billed, 'N') BILLED,
       C.FULL_NAME

FROM SELES V INNER JOIN CLIENTS C ON C.id_client = V.id_client
WHERE 1=1
```

Comment: Verifique os tipo de dados das colunas do inner join, as vezes comparar string com numero pode dar problema ou case sensitive exemplo ID = 1234A é diferente de 1234a
Pela sua reclamação ele não esta achando id_sales e id_product concentre-se nessas colunas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente assim:

```
SELECT   S.ID_SALES,
         S.ID_CLIENT,
         C.FULL_NAME,
         S.SDATE,
         coalesce(S.billed, 'N') BILLED,
         P.product_description product,
         I.amount,
         I.unit_cost, 
         I.unit_cost * I.amount SUBTOTAL,
         coalesce(I.discount, 0) DISCOUNT,
         (I.amount * I.unit_cost) - coalesce(I.discount, 0) TOTAL
FROM     SELES S,
         CLIENTS C,
         ITEM_SELES I,
         PRODUCTS P
WHERE    C.id_client = S.id_client AND
         I.id_sales = S.id_sales AND
         P.id_product = I.id_product
ORDER BY C.FULL_NAME,
         P.product_description
```

Answer (score -1):

Leonardo, tenta conforme abaixo:

```
SELECT S.ID_SALES,
       S.ID_CLIENT,
       C.FULL_NAME,
       S.SDATE,
       coalesce(S.billed, 'N') BILLED,
       P.product_description product,
       I.amount,
       I.unit_cost, 
       I.unit_cost * I.amount SUBTOTAL,
       coalesce(I.discount, 0) DISCOUNT,
       (I.amount * I.unit_cost) - coalesce(I.discount, 0) TOTAL

FROM SELES S INNER JOIN CLIENTS C ON C.id_client = S.id_client
             left outer join ITEM_SELES I ON I.id_sales = S.id_sales
             left outer join PRODUCTS P on P.id_product = I.id_product
WHERE 1=1
ORDER BY C.FULL_NAME,
         P.product_description
```

Pelo que tu explicou, existem dados que satisfazem:

```
C.id_client = S.id_client
```

Entretanto, caso não existam dados que satisfazem:

```
I.id_sales = S.id_sales
```

Ou

```
P.id_product = I.id_product
```

O resultado da operação será um conjunto vazio. Mesmo o primeiro join sendo satisfeito.

[image: Descrição dos produtos de conjuntos possíveis]

Comment: Desse jeito ele funciona parcialmente, traz  os dados da tabela de clientes e vendas, porem não traz das outras tabelas, a de itens e produtos

Comment: Certo, verifica agora se tu tens um registro na tabela ITEM_SELES I que tenha I.id_sales = 10 e verifica se tu tens um registro na tabela SELES S que tenha S.id_sales = 10. O valor 10 é apenas um exemplo para ilustrar.